# Destructuring an array to create html elements

Tags: javascript, dom

i am destructuring an array to create html elements based on the data but i am finding a hard time figuring out how to remove the ',' after destructuring...

```
const elements = data.map((links) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(links);
  return `<div class="links"><p class="${keys[0]}">${links.website}</p>
    <a href=${links.url} class="${keys[1]}">${links.userName}</a></div>`;
});
```

result:

```
<div class="links"><p class="website">Linkedin</p>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/andresilveira717" class="url">André Silveira</a></div> **,**
```

the ',' is appearing on the DOM, how do i remove it ?

I tried to destructuring it to a string but then i am not being able to create elements based on criteria.

Here is the data:

```
export const data = [
  {
    website: "Linkedin",
    url: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/andresilveira717",
    userName: "André Silveira"
  },
  {
    website: "Github",
    url: "https://github.com/the717q",
    userName: "@the717q"
  },
  {
    website: "Twitter",
    url: "https://twitter.com/the717q",
    userName: "@the717q"
  }
];
```

Comment: Your code example isn't complete. Please include the data and an example that can reproduce the problem that you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are attempting to insert a HTML string into the DOM, ensure it is not an array of strings instead of a string. Otherwise you will see commas in the output (most likely due to [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) being implicitly called on the array).

You can use `elements.join('')` to get a html string of all the elements without commas in between them.

```js
const data = [
  {
    website: "Linkedin",
    url: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/andresilveira717",
    userName: "André Silveira"
  },
  {
    website: "Github",
    url: "https://github.com/the717q",
    userName: "@the717q"
  },
  {
    website: "Twitter",
    url: "https://twitter.com/the717q",
    userName: "@the717q"
  }
];

const elements = data.map((links) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(links);
  return `<div class="links"><p class="${keys[0]}">${links.website}</p>
    <a href=${links.url} class="${keys[1]}">${links.userName}</a></div>`;
});


document.querySelector('#root').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', elements.join(''))
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Much appreciated, so simple... LoL !